# Python getattr from locals() fails with AttributeError

Tags: python, getattr

Hopefully this is not the late-night effect, but I'm stumped by a very simple problem:

```
def test_getattr(v0):
    v1 = "test1"
    v2 = "test2"
    v3 = "test3"

    for k, v in locals().items():
        print(k, v)

    print(getattr(locals(), 'v1'))

test_getattr("test0")
```

The output gives the locals() dict items as expected:

> v0 test0
>   v3 test3
>   v1 test1
>   v2 test2

But then dies with:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'v1'

v1 clearly *is* in the locals() 'dict', per the initial output, but then getattr() insists otherwise.

This is my first need to use locals(), but every bit of documentation I can find suggests this should work. What am I missing?

Edit/Update: Many thanks to @martijn for answer below. I managed to use dynamic local variables in getattr() by transiently assigning the local variables to a dummy class:

```
class Attr:
    pass

def test_getattr(v0):
    A = Attr()
    A.v1 = "test1"
    #etc

    print(getattr(A, "v1"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getattr()` retrieves *attributes*, not dictionary keys, and dictionary keys are *not* attributes. `locals()` is just another dictionary, so *use it as one*:

```
print(locals()['v1'])
```

You'll otherwise only find the normal dictionary attributes on `locals()`, such as `keys` and `items` and `__len__` and `__getitem__`:

```
>>> type(locals())
<type 'dict'>
>>> dir(locals())
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
>>> getattr(locals(), 'keys')
<built-in method keys of dict object at 0x10028f168>
```

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for that -- I *was* worried that 'keys' and 'attributes' weren't synonymous in usage even though they can be equivalently expressed in these forms with regular dicts. Unfortunately, what I need to do is dynamically build a SQLAlchemy query filter, with the tables are determined within the function as local variables. I'll ask that as a different question with different tags; I thought I'd reduced it to the minimal working example, but I clearly need to get very specific. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: So you mean there is no way for using `getattr` on dictionaries?

Comment: @TechJS: you can use `getattr()` on dictionaries just fine, dictionaries have attributes *as well*. But attributes are not key-value pairs, that's what you use indexing for.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Aha you mean for example, `key = 'some_key'` we can use `dictionary[key]` instead of directly using `dictionary['some_key']`. Thats equivalent.